# resize2fs shrinking very slow

Tags: linux, filesystems, shrink

I tried to shrink a 60TB ext4 to 50TB and it takes about one week to finish.

I know that should take  much time but it's very slow even my disks underlying are RAID0.

After some research, it seems many people meet this performance bottleneck.

Are there any optional arguments to speed up the shrinking speed?